# Audio port for external mic stops working until reboot

Tags: audio, imac, high-sierra, microphone

iMac 27", High Sierra. External headphones with mic (Bose QC25 if it matters). Everything works fine after system boots up.

Then after some time (can be ~day, can be longer) mic on the headset stops working. Levels on this mic become extremely low to the point where Skype test call won't record anything that I'm speaking. Different apps (Zoom Conference call, Skype) behave same.

Reboot fixes the issue. Disconnecting and connecting headphones - doesn't. Playing with configuration options (System / Sounds) doesn't do any good either.

Any advice?

Comment: I would try an [SMC Reset](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) as it sounds like a (internal) power issue.  If you take your headphones to a different device - do they work there without exhibiting the same symptoms?  What if you use a different headset?

Comment: Same headphones work fine with other device. I've tried two different pairs of headphones - when it stops working, both of them don't work. Just did SMC Reset. Will see if it helps